# how to get the value of an formatted string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Javascript code

> ```
> $("#card").html($card);
> ```

it returns

```
Array
(
    [state] => 6
    [SCARD_PRESENT] => 1
    [SCARD_SWALLOWED] => 1
    [SCARD_POWERED] => 1
    [SCARD_NEGOTIABLE] => 1
    [SCARD_SPECIFIC] => 1
    [SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1] => 1
    [PROTOCOL] => T=1
    [ATR] => 3B8F8001804F0CA000000306030001000000006A
    [Serial] => EE476BB79000
)
```

i want to return the value of [Serial] which is EE476BB79000. 
Please enlighten me.. Thanks

Comment: that is not a 'javascript' array

Comment: What do you mean by `returned`? Do you mean displayed?

Comment: thanks to all who reply. i mean it displayed.

Comment: It seems the data is being returned as a formatted string, so you'll need to write a very simple parser to convert that to something useful. You might even be able to extract the value using a regular expression.

Comment: @RobG how can i display the [Serial] value only because it is a string?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `$card` is an javascript object, then this should work (dot notation)

```
$card.Serial
```

or (bracket notation)

```
$card['Serial']
```

If `$card` is an array, the for the item access we need an index `i`, and for the property, the property:

```
$card[i].Serial
```

or

```
$card[i]['Serial']
```

Please read more about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

> One can think of an object as an associative array (a.k.a. map, dictionary, hash, lookup table). The keys in this array are the names of the object's properties. It's typical when speaking of an object's properties to make a distinction between properties and methods. However, the property/method distinction is little more than a convention. A method is simply a property that can be called, for example if it has a reference to a Function instance as its value.

Comment: If it's an object in an array it would be `$card[0].Serial` but it's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: thanks guys. btw, i use a smart card reader it's read the content of the smart card and it displays that value. im sorry i'm new here

Comment: i've done `$("#card").html($card[0]);`  but it returns letter a in a word Array.

Comment: please test if `$card` is an array, odr with `typeof` whats type it is.

Comment: I'm sorry its a string not an array.

Comment: how can i display the [Serial] value only because it is a string? :(

Comment: is the serial in the string? maybe `JSON.parse($card)` will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a simple parser to convert it to an object like:

```
{
 state: '6',
 SCARD_PRESENT: '1',
 ...
 Serial: 'EE476BB79000'
};
```

Then you can just read the *Serial* property. But to specifically get the serial value, you can find its place in the string, then grab the non–whitespace characters at the end of that line.

The following is commented, ask if you need further help.

```js
var data = 'Array\n' +
'(\n' +
'    [state] => 6\n' +
'    [SCARD_PRESENT] => 1\n' +
'    [SCARD_SWALLOWED] => 1\n' +
'    [SCARD_POWERED] => 1\n' +
'    [SCARD_NEGOTIABLE] => 1\n' +
'    [SCARD_SPECIFIC] => 1\n' +
'    [SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1] => 1\n' +
'    [PROTOCOL] => T=1\n' +
'    [ATR] => 3B8F8001804F0CA000000306030001000000006A\n' +
'    [Serial] => EE476BB79000\n' +
')'

// Find Serial
var idx = data.indexOf('Serial');

// Get the value at the end of that line
var serial = data.substr(idx).match(/\w+\s*$/m);

// match will return an array of matches, or null if none
// were found so test it first.
document.write(serial? serial[0] : '');
```